# Microsoft Access - Loop through form field names for my sql Insert query

Tags: sql, vba, loops, ms-access

I have a form where I want to track asset information for many assets (Assets are already written on the form that the employees fill out)

| Assets | Hours | DSL | DEF | COOL | 10W | 30W | 40W | *Then 12 more fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Asset 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Asset 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| *Then 55 more assets |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The fields are unbound and the field names are exactly the same but just numbered chronologically (asset1, hours1, dsl1...asset2, hours2, dsl2...etc).
I want to know if I can create a loop to save all the rows at the same time by changing the field name.

I'm kind of new to loops, but I wanted to see if it was even possible to change the field name through a loop so I used:

```
For i = 1 To 3
   Me.varlooptest = Me("asset" & i).Value
   MsgBox "checkpoint"
 Next i
```

And what this did was put the asset number into my Me.varlooptest textbox then give me the message "checkpoint" when it worked for each row(and it did).

Knowing that the code to change the field name would work, I tried to save it and it would give me a "Query input must contain at least one table or query" error, and I based this query off my other ones so I feel like it *should* be right but I think I'm missing something

```
 For i = 1 To 3
  Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
  If Len(Me.Controls("asset" & i).Value) <> 0 Then
 insert_shop_qry = "INSERT INTO tbl_shop(tracking_shop_id,asset_id,hours,dsl,def,cool,W10,W30,W40,glass,fittings,airfilter,wheels,hose,mirrors,battery,lights,grease,leaks,blowout,comment) SELECT " & Me.shop_tracking_id & " AS tracking_shop_id, " & _
 Me("asset" & i).Value & " AS asset_id, " & _
 Me("hours" & i).Value & " AS hours, '" & _
 Me("dsl" & i).Value & "' AS dsl, '" & _
 Me("def" & i).Value & "' AS def, '" & _
 Me("cool" & i).Value & "' AS cool, '" & _
 Me("W10_" & i).Value & "' AS W10, '" & _
 Me("W30_" & i).Value & "' AS W30, '" & _
 Me("W40_" & i).Value & "' AS W40, '" & _
 Me("glass" & i).Value & "' AS glass, '" & _
 Me("fittings" & i).Value & "' AS fittings, '" & _
 Me("airfilter" & i).Value & "' AS airfilter, '" & _
 Me("wheels" & i).Value & "' AS wheels, '" & _
 Me("hose" & i).Value & "' AS hose, '" & _
 Me("mirrors" & i).Value & "' AS mirrors, '" & _
 Me("battery" & i).Value & "' AS battery, '" & _
 Me("lights" & i).Value & "' AS lights, '" & _
 Me("grease" & i).Value & "' AS hose, '" & _
 Me("leaks" & i).Value & "' AS mirrors, '" & _
 Me("blowout" & i).Value & "' AS blowout, '" & _
 Me("comment" & i).Value & "' AS comment );"
  CurrentDb.Execute insert_shop_qry
     End If
   Next i

  MsgBox "saved!"
```

Comment: Use `VALUES(" & ... & ")"` instead of `SELECT`. Why not use bound form?

Comment: Make sure you correct `Me("grease" & i).Value & "' AS hose, '"`

Comment: With Values() don't need alias field name: `Me("grease" & i) & "','" & `. In either version, not necessary to specify Value because it is default property.

Comment: Actually, the SELECT should work if you remove the unpaired `)` at end of `comment` concatenation. Semi-colon is not needed for action SQL.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy thank you! I also somehow messed up `Me("leaks" & i).Value & "' AS mirrors, '"`

Comment: @June7 YES!! i removed the ) and ; and it works perfectly! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Look at comments under question!*
Thank you @MichaelMurphy and @June7; it works PERFECTLY!!

Edit: written explanation

Me being dumb, these fields were incorrect (thank you @MichaelMurphy):

```
 Me("grease" & i).Value & "' AS hose, '" & _
 Me("leaks" & i).Value & "' AS mirrors, '" & _
```

Corrected to:

```
 Me("grease" & i).Value & "' AS grease, '" & _
 Me("leaks" & i).Value & "' AS leaks, '" & _
```

And I had an unpaired parenthesis at the end of comment and I guess SQL doesn't use semicolons (thank you @June7):

```
 Me("comment" & i).Value & "' AS comment );"
```

Corrected to:

```
 Me("comment" & i).Value & "' AS comment "
```

So the corrected and working code is:

```
  For i = 1 To 3
  Set db = DBEngine.Workspaces(0).Databases(0)
  If Len(Me.Controls("asset" & i).Value) <> 0 Then
 insert_shop_qry = "INSERT INTO tbl_shop(tracking_shop_id,asset_id,hours,dsl,def,cool,W10,W30,W40,glass,fittings,airfilter,wheels,hose,mirrors,battery,lights,grease,leaks,blowout,comment) SELECT " & Me.shop_tracking_id & " AS tracking_shop_id, " & _
 Me("asset" & i).Value & " AS asset_id, '" & _
 Me("hours" & i).Value & "' AS hours, '" & _
 Me("dsl" & i).Value & "' AS dsl, '" & _
 Me("def" & i).Value & "' AS def, '" & _
 Me("cool" & i).Value & "' AS cool, '" & _
 Me("W10_" & i).Value & "' AS W10, '" & _
 Me("W30_" & i).Value & "' AS W30, '" & _
 Me("W40_" & i).Value & "' AS W40, '" & _
 Me("glass" & i).Value & "' AS glass, '" & _
 Me("fittings" & i).Value & "' AS fittings, '" & _
 Me("airfilter" & i).Value & "' AS airfilter, '" & _
 Me("wheels" & i).Value & "' AS wheels, '" & _
 Me("hose" & i).Value & "' AS hose, '" & _
 Me("mirrors" & i).Value & "' AS mirrors, '" & _
 Me("battery" & i).Value & "' AS battery, '" & _
 Me("lights" & i).Value & "' AS lights, '" & _
 Me("grease" & i).Value & "' AS grease, '" & _
 Me("leaks" & i).Value & "' AS leaks, '" & _
 Me("blowout" & i).Value & "' AS blowout, '" & _
 Me("comment" & i).Value & "' AS comment "
  CurrentDb.Execute insert_shop_qry
  Else
    Cancel = True
     End If
   Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider separating SQL and VBA with use of [QueryDef parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/parameters-collection-dao) and a saved Access query:

**SQL** *(save as query object, no VBA variables, quotes, ampersands line breaks)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [prm_shop_tracking_id] INTEGER, [prm_asset] INTEGER, [prm_hours] DOUBLE, 
           [prm_dsl] TEXT, [prm_def] TEXT, [prm_cool] TEXT, 
           [prm_W10] TEXT, [prm_W30] TEXT, [prm_W40] TEXT,
           [prm_glass] TEXT, [prm_fittings] TEXT, [prm_airfilter] TEXT, 
           [prm_wheels] TEXT, [prm_hose] TEXT, [prm_mirrors] TEXT, 
           [prm_battery] TEXT, [prm_lights] TEXT, [prm_grease] TEXT, 
           [prm_leaks] TEXT, [prm_blowout] TEXT, [prm_comment] TEXT;
INSERT INTO tbl_shop (tracking_shop_id, asset_id, hours, dsl, def, cool,
                      W10, W30, W40, glass, fittings, airfilter, wheels,
                      hose, mirrors, battery, lights, grease, leaks,
                      blowout, comment) 
VALUES ([prm_shop_tracking_id], [prm_asset], [prm_hours], [prm_dsl],
        [prm_def], [prm_cool], [prm_W10], [prm_W30], [prm_W40],
        [prm_glass], [prm_fittings], [prm_airfilter], [prm_wheels],
        [prm_hose], [prm_mirrors], [prm_battery], [prm_lights],
        [prm_grease], [prm_leaks], [prm_blowout], [prm_comment]);
```

**VBA** *(no SQL commands, punctuation, or syntax)*

```vb
' INITIALIZE DAO OBJECTS ONCE
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdef = db.QueryDefs("mySavedInsertQuery")

For i = 1 To 3
    If Len(Me.Controls("asset" & i).Value) <> 0 Then
        ' BIND PARAMETERS
        qdef![prm_shop_tracking_id] = Me.shop_tracking_id
        qdef![prm_asset] = Me("asset" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_hours] = Me("hours" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_dsl] = Me("dsl" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_def] = Me("def" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_cool] = Me("cool" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_W10] = Me("W10_" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_W30] = Me("W30_" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_W40] = Me("W40_" & i).Value 
        qdef![prm_glass] = Me("glass" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_fittings] = Me("fittings" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_airfilter] = Me("airfilter" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_wheels] = Me("wheels" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_hose] = Me("hose" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_mirrors] = Me("mirrors" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_battery] = Me("battery" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_lights] = Me("lights" & i).Value 
        qdef![prm_grease] = Me("grease" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_leaks] = Me("leaks" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_blowout] = Me("blowout" & i).Value
        qdef![prm_comment] = Me("comment" & i).Value

        ' EXECUTE ACTION
        qdef.Execute
    End If
Next i

' RELEASE DAO OBJECTS
Set qdef = Nothing: Set db = Nothing
```